# javascript/html autocomplete textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a web page which has a requirement of many autocomplete textboxes. As I am new to javascript, it is very tough for me to make my own autocomplete textbox. So I have searched many examples from the internet, but they only work for a single textbox. This means I cannot use the same js file to make another autocomplete textbox. I didn't find any such examples on stackoverflow either. Can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use JQuery with the AutoSuggest plugin.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

Include the JS libraries (see the documentation above), then do this in HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="autocomplete" name="n1" />
<input type="text" class="autocomplete" name="n2" />
<input type="text" class="autocomplete" name="n3" />
<input type="text" class="autocomplete" name="n4" />
```

Then add an Autocomplete to the CSS-class in your Javascript:

```
var data = "Core Selectors Attributes Traversing Manipulation CSS Events Effects Ajax Utilities".split(" ");
$(".autocomplete").autocomplete(data);
```

Answer (score 41):

Here's a solution to create autocomplete with No JQUERY or No JAVASCRIPT..
just plain html5 an input box and a datalist tag..

lean more about it [here](http://www.cheezycode.com/2015/09/create-auto-complete-dropdown-using.html)

```html
<input type="text" id="txtAutoComplete" list="languageList" />
<!--your input textbox-->
<datalist id="languageList">
    <option value="HTML" />
    <option value="CSS" />
    <option value="JavaScript" />
    <option value="SQL" />
    <option value="PHP" />
    <option value="jQuery" />
    <option value="Bootstrap" />
    <option value="Angular" />
    <option value="ASP.NET" />
    <option value="XML" />
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Everyone else seems to think I want yet another dependency in my code, when a simple solution like this does exactly what is required and no more, without the extra baggage.

Comment: In all fairness, many answered long before Cheezy, when html5 implementations in browsers was wonky to nonexistant. As time moves on, some solutions become more useful than others.

Answer (score 12):

I recommend to check this:

http://complete-ly.appspot.com/

The simple case should meet your requirements:

```
var cly = completely(document.getElementById('a-div-wrapping-your-autocomplete-box');
cly.options = [ 'your','array','of','options','(possibly sorted somehow)'];
```

Answer (score 7):

The `AutoSuggest` plugin has been deprecated and is now included in `jQuery UI`.

Check this out:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to web development I'd recommend you to use jquery and [jqueryUI package](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). The link above is to demo page where you can play with different types of datasources.
I've copied an example which uses simple array as a datasource

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",         "AppleScript",
            "Asp",              "BASIC",
            "C",                "C++",
            "Clojure",              "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",           "Erlang",
            "Fortran",              "Groovy",
            "Haskell",              "Java",
            "JavaScript",           "Lisp",
            "Perl",             "PHP",
            "Python",               "Ruby",
            "Scala",                "Scheme"
        ];
        $( ".tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>

<div><input class="tags" type="text" /></div>
<div><input class="tags" type="text" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy method, just use the onkeyup event :

```
<input type="text" id="a" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<br/>
<br/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("a").value;
    document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = x;   
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```