# Pre populate text box from stored data

Tags: javascript, ajax, textbox

can someone give me an idea how to do this or what is the correct term for this kind of textbox?

[image]

(Original at https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybeag.png)

Comment: thanks for the edit because i cannot yet add an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8020/Auto-complete-Control

and also this: 
http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/gr/column5/index.html

and take a look at this question: [javascript/html autocomplete textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203251/javascript-html-autocomplete-textbox)

Comment: This is a very good starting point, but for real-world applications you will probably need Ajax as well.

Comment: is this advisable if the autocomplete tag array are more than thousands?

Comment: you will need to use ajax, but you can try and see about the performence