# Web - adding database values to textbox's autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know if this is possible or not. What I want to do is add dynamic values to textbox's auto complete.

For example, I have textBox1 and I input "myUserName" and then press submit button then the page refreshes. When I type "m" to textBox1, just below the textBox1, the intellisense or auto complete turn up and the value "myUserName" is showing.

So my question is how do I add data to textBox1's auto complete. Is it possible? If yes please tell me how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript/html autocomplete textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203251/javascript-html-autocomplete-textbox)

Comment: [How to implement a google suggest-like input field?
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795843/how-to-implement-a-google-suggest-like-input-field)