# Angularjs active directory search

Tags: angular, active-directory

Okay so I am still relatively new to angular environment. I currently have a single web application built out with Angular where users are required to type in names and locations. One of the biggest complaints that users have is that they cannot search for people using active directory. Is there away for me to add this search function so that users can just look up individuals instead of populating the table?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Are you using AngularJS (Angular v1) or Angular (Angular V2 or higher)? Your title says one, your tag says the other.

Comment: But in either case, an Angular application runs completely in the browser, so it cannot directly access Active Directory. There are libraries that you can use such as this one: https://auth0.com/authenticate/angular2/active-directory/

Comment: Thank you Deborah

Answer (score 0):

> Is there away for me to add this search function so that users can just look up individuals instead of populating the table?

Angular apps run entirely in the browser. And the browser is by design unable to do the AD lookup.

So in order to find you need to call an API endpoint to either validate the username entered or to search for suggestions. You can then do the AD lookup server-side using the environment you are using to power all other features of your app.

For suggestions, refer to [javascript/html autocomplete textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203251/javascript-html-autocomplete-textbox) on how to generate the autocomplete textbox.