# How to add autocomplete feature in node.js search bar?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Node as the server side language and a mongodb database. I wanted to know how can you add the auto complete functionality in the search bar. For example, I have a property "materialCode" in my object and when I type in say "12" I want a drop down box showing all the materialCodes that start with 12 in that particular collection. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: could you please specify which frontend or templating engine?

Comment: I am using ejs templating engine

Comment: I used ejs template engine now could you please check? If you are facing any error what error you are facing?

Comment: Thanks! it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally We will do that in front end. If you are using html5 then it can be easily done.(Assuming you are using any template engine or angular or react.) Get all the data from backend(node) using any service call (Say you stored data in **allMaterialCode**). Then loop through that **allMaterialCode** and send **materialCode** values to html5 dataList like below. (Bind materialCode by looping allMaterialsCode). (Assuming you are running node ejs server)

```
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
        <% 
            var dataObj = ["12","1223","12456","12345","13322","9877"];
        %>
        <%
            for ( let singleItem of dataObj ) {
        %>
            <option value='<%= singleItem %>'>
        <%
            }
        %>
</datalist>
```

These links might help.

[AutoCompleteHTMl SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203251/javascript-html-autocomplete-textbox)

[w3schools autocomplete](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp)